# Grouping columns in MYSQL, complex query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this MYSQL Query and I need the columns to be grouped up next to eachother, I just can't seem to do it....

```
SELECT Supervisor,
   (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 2 THEN (COUNT(`ID Number`)) END) AS `Monday`,
   (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 3 THEN (COUNT(`ID Number`)) END) AS `Tuesday`,
   (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 4 THEN (COUNT(`ID Number`)) END) AS `Wednesday`,
   (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 5 THEN (COUNT(`ID Number`)) END) AS `Thursday`,
   (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 6 THEN (COUNT(`ID Number`)) END) AS `Friday`,
   (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 7 THEN (COUNT(`ID Number`)) END) AS `Saturday`
FROM payroll.employeedatanew_copy
INNER JOIN payroll.employeehours ON employeedatanew_copy.`ID Number` = employeehours.employeeid
WHERE workdate BETWEEN "2013-10-28" AND "2013-11-02"
GROUP BY workdate, supervisor
```

Here is my result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9kSz.png

This is what I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRNmJ.png

Comment: In the "what I want" image, the value for each row is that same for each workday, is that what is expected?

Comment: Remove the `workdate` field from the `group by`.

Comment: @MikeBrant, yeah I had just used the same dataset for each date, so values are the same :).

Comment: Thanks Barranka, but that just wasn't enough, perfect answer is below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this:

```
SELECT Supervisor,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 2 THEN 1 END) `Monday`,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 3 THEN 1 END) `Tuesday`,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 4 THEN 1 END) `Wednesday`,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 5 THEN 1 END) `Thursday`,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 6 THEN 1 END) `Friday`,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 7 THEN 1 END) `Saturday`
FROM payroll.employeedatanew_copy
JOIN payroll.employeehours ON employeedatanew_copy.`ID Number` = employeehours.employeeid
WHERE workdate BETWEEN "2013-10-28" AND "2013-11-02"
GROUP BY supervisor
```

Alternatively, the `count`s could be replaced with:

```
SUM(DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 2) `Monday`
```

This works based on the fact that `true` equals `1` in MySQL but will not necessarily work in other DBMS.

Comment: It should be noted that grouping by `workdate` basically put all workdate=2 rows first, then workdate=3 rows, etc.  You don't want that grouping at all.

Comment: Right. That's why `Darrent Bent` was there more than once in different rows.